# Meaning of blocks in LDO datasheet

Tags: voltage-regulator, datasheet

I am using the regulator for a sensor application. When look closely to block diagram of LP2951, there are some blocks marked with lable that I have not figure out.

(1): the arrow to the Amplifier is trange to me, never see it on textbook but many times in component datasheets. What is purpose of it?

(2): Diode to ground. What is purpose of it ? I think it protects Shutdown pin. But not sure

(3): As my understanding, this is a 60mV ref voltage to Comparator. But the why another side connects to FB line

Thank you

[image: LP2591 Block Diagrams]

Comment: You have observations but no questions about them. Block diagrams are very high level simplifications about actual circuits and don't depict actual circuits.

Comment: I edited the question. Agreed they are high level block, but must servs for some explaination purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which datasheet you are reading as I found multiple datasheets that don't have the diagrams you post.

1. The arrow simply means that the shutdown pin controls the error amplifier.
2. There is really no diode, but the input sort of looks like a diode so it is a good simplification. In real life the shutdown input goes to a transistor base which has a grounded emitter so it really looks like a diode.
3. That is not a reference voltage for comparator. The reference is the 1.23V. The voltage of feedback pin has an added offset before comparing to the reference.

Comment: I am using Lp2591 from On semi

Comment: It does not matter any more. Other datasheets even had the full transistor level diagrams.

Comment: I just found an old datasheet from NatSemi (TI) with full transistors. Look beautiful. 
Thanks for your reply

Comment: @anhvanthe Even the full transistor schematic is just a representation. A 1:10 current mirror takes several components with discrete parts but can be made with a transistor in wafer level with several inputs/outputs of varying sizes to give 1:10 ratio, AND gates made with a MOSFET with two gates and so on.

Comment: just an additional comment: I found photo die of this IC 
http://usmicrowaves.com/ldoreg/LP2951-5.htm